# Is there any way/api to set a certain row to be shown at the top in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When I don't do/call any grid api, it, of course, displays the grid-look with the very first index row. But here what I'd like to achieve is with ag-grid is that I want to set a certain row to be shown at the top. I've tried using `ensureIndexVisible` api with `targetIndex` on the `firstDataRendered` event hook but it causes an awkward user experience as it scrolls down to the row after it finishes rendering. So I'm wondering if there's any other approach for this needs yet with un-awkward user experience. Here's my trying snippet:

**Using Angular 7**

```
// template
<ag-grid-angular
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (firstDataRendered)="onRendered()">
</ag-grid-angular>

// component
onRendered(): void {
  const targetIndex = this.getTargetIndex();

  this.gridOptions.api.ensureIndexVisible(targetIndex, 'top');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Row Pinning feature** of ag-grid to pin single or multiple rows to the top or bottom of the grid always.

The api to set pinned rows is `setPinnedTopRowData`.

```
this.gridApi.setPinnedTopRowData(rows);
```

Sample plunker which demonstrates the row pinning feature - https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Read more about row pinning in the ag-grid documentation here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/